# PHP Artisan Tinker not working with Laravel 5.5.16

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I run php artisan tinker but it didn't work it just show a message like this

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\app_tpa>php artisan tinker
```

> [ErrorException]
>   rmdir(C:\Users\KIMUNG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\php-xdg-runtime-dir-fallback-): Directory not empty

I tried to run `composer require laravel/tinker`, but it doesn't fix my problem

Comment: Delete temp directories related to the artisan tinker `php-xdg-runtime-dir-fallback....`   from   `C:\Users\KIMUNG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\`

Comment: This is almost certainly an OS/environment problem only you can figure out. What is in that directory? What is holding onto a file in that directory? That is, your real question is the same as this one: https://superuser.com/q/117902/609232

Comment: @webDev thanks.. you saved my whole life

Comment: @webDev atos a ku anjar to wartosan sareng upi nuhun pisan euy.. duh kumaha bae rokok ? kopi atuh ? bahe moal

Comment: @NNN English Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is now resolved as per these github issues:

[laravel/tinker#29](https://github.com/laravel/tinker/issues/29)

[bobthecow/psysh#430](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/issues/430)

The proper solution now is to do `composer update`