# laravel 5.5 : php artisan tinker : ErrorException : Directory not empty

Tags: php, laravel, tinker

I am using windows.
... In my CMD, was using tinker, myql, serve, etc... and they all went well...

Suddenly, when i exit tinker and enter tinker again... this error comes up

`[ErrorException]
  rmdir(C:\Users\robert\AppData\Local\Temp\php-xdg-runtime-dir-fallback-): Directory not empty`

Then sure enough, I tried removing, can't
I tried renaming the folder to something else, it worked... "php artisan tinker" works... but I can't run usual command

`$user = App\User::all();`

Then I exit... then enter tinker again... again the 

    `[ErrorException]
      rmdir(C:\Users\robert\AppData\Local\Temp\php-xdg-runtime-dir-fallback-): 
    Directory not empty`

Firstly, I searched similar problems but the solution doesn't work for me permanently ([PHP Artisan Tinker not working with Laravel 5.5.16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46792892/php-artisan-tinker-not-working-with-laravel-5-5-16))

Secondly, I tried making `laravel new NewProject` , run tinker... still same ErrorException

Thirdly, I tried `composer update` or `composer require laravel/tinker` ... then add the `Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,` inside config/app.php => providers.... still same ErrorException

Btw , this is the full length error

```
    php artisan tinker -vvv --ansi
    ?    [37;41m                                                                                                    ?[39;49m
        ?[37;41m     [ErrorException]                                                                                ?[39;49m
        ?[37;41m  rmdir(C:\Users\robert\AppData\Local\Temp\php-xdg-runtime-dir-fallback-): Directory not empty  ?[39;49m
    ?[37;41m                                                                                                ?[39;49m

```
?[33mException trace:?[39m
 () at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\dnoegel\php-xdg-base-dir\src\Xdg.php:110?[39m
 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at ?[32mn/a:n/a?[39m
 rmdir() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\dnoegel\php-xdg-base-dir\src\Xdg.php:110?[39m
 XdgBaseDir\Xdg->getRuntimeDir() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\ConfigPaths.php:139?[39m
 Psy\ConfigPaths::getRuntimeDir() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\Configuration.php:348?[39m
 Psy\Configuration->getRuntimeDir() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\Shell.php:173?[39m
 Psy\Shell->getDefaultCommands() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:1163?[39m
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->init() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:431?[39m
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->add() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\Shell.php:134?[39m
 Psy\Shell->add() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:415?[39m
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->addCommands() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\tinker\src\Console\TinkerCommand.php
:54?[39m
 Laravel\Tinker\Console\TinkerCommand->handle() at ?[32mn/a:n/a?[39m
 call_user_func_array() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:29?[39m
 Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illumina
te\Container\BoundMethod.php:87?[39m
 Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Bo
undMethod.php:31?[39m
 Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
:549?[39m
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:180?[
39m
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:262?[39m
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command
.php:167?[39m
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:888?[39m
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:224?[39m
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:125?[39m
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application
.php:88?[39m
 Illuminate\Console\Application->run() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.
php:121?[39m
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at ?[32mC:\xampp\htdocs\blog\artisan:37?[39m
```

```

Can anybody please help?
Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue in laravel 5.3. I just removed psysh folder inside  php-xdg-runtime-dir-fallback- and it works temporarily.

Comment: What do u mean by temporary ? Did u know why it happened ?

Comment: no, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:  The below is no longer necessary.  Version 0.8.13 is already out and fixes the issue.

---

Same issue in Laravel 5.5.  I just downgraded to the previous version of Psy Shell until it gets fixed by going into the project directory and entering

```
composer require psy/psysh:0.8.11
```

at the command line to downgrade to the previous version of Psy Shell.  They'll fix it eventually and then I'll update again to the new version.

Comment: It's already fixed! Remove this from your composer dependencies before you forget ;)

Comment: Done.  Thanks @bobthecow.  It's a really great shell.  Appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with an underlying library on Windows. See [bobthecow/psysh#430](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/issues/430) for more info and a temporary fix until a workaround is released.

Comment: Thanks! After the `composer update` it is working again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found out the solution... it may not be the best one... or temporary solution, i guess

I basically manually delete the psysh folder every time before tinker

`rmdir c:\Users\robert\AppData\Local\Temp\php-xdg-runtime-dir-fallback-\psysh`
then tinker

Oh btw, above I mentioned I already tried removing but failed, but when I tried removing `psysh` instead of "php-xdg-runtime-dir-fallback-" , then it worked... Also it turns out the tinker commands etc works ok too... Again u still have to remove manually though.

Anybody with better solution, please add below, I am really eager to know why or how come it happened? And most importantly more permanent solution.

I already posted this question or searched similar issues in laracasts, but no answers yet.

Cheers